# itext pdf change default font size in Paragraph not working

Tags: java, android, pdf, itext

while using itext5 in android to display pdf from XHTML am trying to change the font size but it's not reflecting.
I would like to know the substitutes(or hack) for CSS as itext5 is not supporting CSS.

```
 preparedText = output.toString("UTF-8");

 list = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(preparedText, null);
//   URL path      =Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("fontname");
//    FontFactory.register(path.toString(), "test_font");
  Font titleFont = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD,7f);
  paragraph.setFont(titleFont);
  paragraph.addAll(list);
  publishProgress(88);
            // write to document
            document.open();
            document.newPage();
            Paragraph p= new Paragraph(paragraph);
            p.setFont(titleFont);
            document.add(p);
            document.close();
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: its is showing default font not able to change it, font is not reflecting in pdf

Comment: @nikitasoloman Does my answer help? If it does, please accept it. If it does not, please indicate what is missing.

Comment: no we used css resolver thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The font you set in a paragraph applies to all text added to the paragraph afterwards, it does not change the previously added text. To set the font of the text you add to a paragraph in the constructor, there is a constructor that also accepts a font parameter.

Thus, instead of

```
Paragraph p= new Paragraph(paragraph);
p.setFont(titleFont);
```

use

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph(paragraphText, titleFont);
```

or

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.setFont(titleFont);
p.add(paragraphText);
```

Comment: For any elements that already have a style (like the elements parsed by `XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList`) you cannot change the font by setting the font of a container element (like the paragraph you add those elements to). Instead you'd have to iterate over the individual elements, recurse into their constituents, and adapt the font therein. Or better, already generate those elements with the desired font.